# Select widget value appearing in POST but not cleaned_data

Tags: django

One of my forms has a Select widget that is not working properly. Using the VS Code debugger, I found that the data is showing up in `POST` but not `cleaned_data`. Here is my code:

*views.py*

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'quotes/index.html', {
            'form': QuoteRequestForm(),
        })
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuoteRequestForm(request.POST)

        # edit 2
        pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
        pp.pprint(request.POST)

        g_recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        ip = get_client_ip(request)

        api_response = verify(g_recaptcha_response, ip)
        api_response_content = json.loads(str(api_response.content, encoding='utf-8'))

        if not api_response_content['success'] or api_response.status_code != 200:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error submitting the form.')
            messages.error(request, 'Please prove you are human by clicking the last checkbox and possibly completing a security challenge.')

            return render(request, 'quotes/index.html', {'form': form})

        if form.is_valid():
            quote_request = form.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Thank you for submitting a quote request. We will contact you via phone or email within 1-3 business days.')

            return redirect('quotes:index')

        messages.error(request, 'There was an error submitting the form.')

        return render(request, 'quotes/index.html', {
            'form': form,
        })

    return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

*forms.py*

```
class QuoteRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        label='',
        choices=Contact.title_choices,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'data-label': 'Title',
            },
        ),
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=35,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'First Name',
        }),
    )
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=70,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Last Name',
        }),
    )
    family_first = forms.BooleanField(
        required=False,
        label='Family Name Is First',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput(),
    )
    phone = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=20,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Phone',
        }),
        validators=[RegexValidator(PHONE_REGEX, 'Enter a valid U.S. phone number.')],
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='',
        max_length=200,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Email',
        }),
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        label='',
        max_length=500,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Summary of Site Contents (please be detailed)\nE.g. an attractive home page, an about page, a quote request form, and a portfolio with private submission form and management page.',
            'rows': 6,
        }),
    )

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        cleaned_data['title'] = int(cleaned_data['title'])

        try:
            cleaned_data['phone'] = PHONE_REGEX.sub(
                r'\2\3\4', cleaned_data['phone']
            )
        except KeyError:
            # 'phone' not in 'cleaned_data'.
            # Error handled in RegexValidator.
            return cleaned_data

        # Retrieve contact first by email, then by phone number.
        # If successful, update. Otherwise, create new.
        try:
            contact = Contact.objects.get(email=cleaned_data['email'])

            contact.update(
                title=cleaned_data['title'],
                first_name=cleaned_data['first_name'],
                last_name=cleaned_data['last_name'],
                family_first=cleaned_data['family_first'],
                phone=cleaned_data['phone'],
            )
        except Contact.DoesNotExist:
            try:
                contact = Contact.objects.get(phone=cleaned_data['phone'])

                contact.update(
                    title=cleaned_data['title'],
                    first_name=cleaned_data['first_name'],
                    last_name=cleaned_data['last_name'],
                    family_first=cleaned_data['family_first'],
                    email=cleaned_data['email'],
                )
            except Contact.DoesNotExist:
                contact = Contact.objects.create(
                    title=cleaned_data['title'],
                    first_name=cleaned_data['first_name'],
                    last_name=cleaned_data['last_name'],
                    family_first=cleaned_data['family_first'],
                    email=cleaned_data['email'],
                    phone=cleaned_data['phone'],
                )

        cleaned_data['contact'] = contact

        return cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = QuoteRequest
        fields = [
            'title', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'family_first',
            'email', 'phone', 'description',
        ]
```

*models.py*

```py
class Contact(TimestampedModel):
    title_choices = [
        (0, 'Mx.'),
        (1, 'Ms.'),
        (2, 'Mrs.'),
        (3, 'Mr.'),
        (4, 'Dr.'),
    ]

    title = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=title_choices)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    family_first = models.BooleanField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class QuoteRequest(TimestampedModel):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
```

Submitting the form gives me the following error:

```py
Internal Server Error: /quote/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/quotes/views.py", line 30, in index
    return render(request, 'quotes/index.html', {'form': form})
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 986, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 670, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 795, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 857, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 308, in non_field_errors
    return self.errors.get(NON_FIELD_ERRORS, self.error_class(error_class='nonfield'))
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 175, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 377, in full_clean
    self._clean_form()
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 404, in _clean_form
    cleaned_data = self.clean()
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/example/quotes/forms.py", line 72, in clean
    cleaned_data['title'] = int(cleaned_data['title'])
KeyError: 'title'
[29/Jul/2020 22:42:35] "POST /quote/ HTTP/1.1" 500 207974
```

It may be worth mentioning that I tried creating a custom Select widget (a class inheriting from `Select` that does nothing except link in a modified template), but replacing with Django's Select widget didn't prove successful. How do I fix this? Restarting the development server didn't lead me to a solution, either. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

*index.html*

```html
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}

{% block js %}  <!-- reCAPTCHA v2 JS -->
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<section class="page">
  {% if messages %}
  <div class="container">
    {% include 'home/messages.html' %}
  </div>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="container max-w-480px">
    <form method="POST">
      <h3 class="h3">{% block title %}Request a Quote{% endblock %}</h3>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.non_field_errors }}
      {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
      {% if field.name == 'title' %}
      {{ form.title.errors }}
      {{ form.first_name.errors }}
      {{ form.last_name.errors }}
      {{ form.family_first.errors }}
      <div class="name">
        {{ form.title }}
        {{ form.first_name }}
        {{ form.last_name }}
        {{ form.family_first.widget }}
        {% include 'fields/custom_checkbox.html' with field=form.family_first %}
      </div>
      {% elif field.name != 'first_name' and field.name != 'last_name' and field.name != 'family_first' %}
      {{ field.errors }}
      {{ field }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <div
        class="g-recaptcha"
        data-sitekey="{{ recaptcha_site_key }}"
        data-theme="dark"
      ></div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Submit Request">
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

*rendered HTML*

```html
<form method="POST">
  <h3 class="h3">Request a Quote</h3>
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="nupIoxUpFUm2lqyJcZV5URqPl1VxheIrPp14IPbrg376HwslUrqzNcn7ZJPKU6Zm">
  <div class="name">
    <select name="title" class="form-control" data-label="Title" autocomplete="off" id="id_title">
      <option value="0">Mx.</option>
      <option value="1">Ms.</option>
      <option value="2">Mrs.</option>
      <option value="3">Mr.</option>
      <option value="4">Dr.</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="35" required="" id="id_first_name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="70" required="" id="id_last_name">
    <div class="input-group input-group-checkbox" data-target-input="nearest">
      <label class="form-control" for="id_family_first">Family Name Is First</label>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <input type="checkbox" name="family_first" id="id_family_first">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" maxlength="200" required="" id="id_email">
  <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" maxlength="20" required="" id="id_phone">
  <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Summary of Site Contents (please be detailed)
E.g. an attractive home page, an about page, a quote request form, and a portfolio with private submission form and management page." maxlength="500" required="" id="id_description"></textarea><div><small>0/500</small></div>
  <!-- reCAPTCHA would be here -->
  <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Submit Request">
</form>
```

**Edit 2**

Pretty printed `request.POST` in *views.py*.

*Output*

```py
{ 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'fL0n76O27oycoUHbGvOKnD3pPefyJYfcHGCJro54IxjgK0BNoXjegY0HtW9LmQw7',
  'description': 'This is a test.',
  'email': 'email@example.com',
  'first_name': 'Matt',
  'g-recaptcha-response': '03AGdBq27KT5kGjvknN9VTcc77Eo7Tg5b-mOSur0jjih8eGr0UYvunA4ExCIgwkkqykOojjfvDb01a-jIzBp2dWm4hUDTh21MU0x8zlDtrMCyu_D4TjfNvmwYvwW6pPDPZmKwM2Qwrc7fEExjdblRh6pTtSSgchsxz7aJV7Es-dlQYxG7AMXehD-j1cRKxqp5tqytWrfohoy6uZGL7J6PlvMiZaGU0VgYT4YKazhtESyiEE95iStIWBCYr0UVrGZGWfCBwh0_uhD4G-zgGmhtA0g23jseg2YU4jACnO5BpG7w9caDfqd8qRWWIV_qaa6lmuRr2E_e_TsmjcA72dHriElwcrapJRpJgUnUBH-oOIORD7U3Qh4thEd5p84UEJBhVfAwUbmoAna_h5E9R-6Vp5J4_Y5nuOR3lYw',
  'last_name': 'McCarthy',
  'phone': '1234567890',
  'title': '3'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by your use of a `Select` widget on a `MultipleChoiceField`. You probably don't need multiple choices for a title so update your form with the following:

```py
class QuoteRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.ChoiceField(  # this line has changed
        label='',
        choices=Contact.title_choices,
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'data-label': 'Title',
            },
        ),
    )
    # other stuff
```

---

My previous answer:

This might be caused by the fact that you have named fields in the `ModelForm.Meta` class that don't correspond with existing fields on your `QuoteRequest` model.

Try updating your `ModelForm.Meta` to only include the fields that exist on your `QuoteRequest` model:

```py
class QuoteRequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # fields
    # clean method
    class Meta:
        model = QuoteRequest
        fields = ['description']
```

Comment: Thanks fellow Matt, it solved my issue. I actually received a suggestion to use `TypedMultipleChoiceField` with `coerce=int` on the IRC channel, which didn't solve the issue but was a better suggestion than what I previously had, so now I've combined your two answers and used `TypedChoiceField` with `coerce=int`. Onto the next error!