# dropdown select showing up in views.py but not in the clean method in forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a django template as follows

```
<div class="container-fluid lineitem_form_container">
    <div class="inner_holder">
        <h2>Add Line Item</h2>
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'Dashboard:lineitems' %}" class="col-md-6">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Line Item Name:</label>
                {{ form.name }}
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="{{ form.category.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Category:</label>
                {{ form.category }}
                {{ form.new_category }}
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="{{ form.segment.id_for_label }}" class="form-label">Segment:</label>
                {{ form.segment }}
                {{ form.new_segment }}
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        // JavaScript code to toggle visibility of new category/segment fields
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var categoryDropdown = document.querySelector('#id_category');
            var newCategoryField = document.querySelector('#id_new_category');

            var segmentDropdown = document.querySelector('#id_segment');
            var newSegmentField = document.querySelector('#id_new_segment');

            // Initial state
            newCategoryField.style.display = 'none';
            newSegmentField.style.display = 'none';

            categoryDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
                newCategoryField.style.display = categoryDropdown.value === 'new_category' ? 'block' :
                    'none';
            });

            segmentDropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
                newSegmentField.style.display = segmentDropdown.value === 'new_segment' ? 'block' :
                    'none';
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

**This is my forms.py**

```
class CustomTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['attrs'] = {'class': 'form-control'}
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class LineItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    new_category = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        required=False,
        label='New Category',
        widget=CustomTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter new category'}),
    )
    new_segment = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        required=False,
        label='New Segment',
        widget=CustomTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Enter new segment'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        fields = ['name', 'category', 'segment']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
            'segment': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}),
        }
        
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set the queryset for the category and segment fields based on the user
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=user)
        self.fields['segment'].queryset = Segment.objects.filter(user=user)

        # Set the choices for the category and segment fields based on the user's choices
        self.fields['category'].choices = Category.CATEGORY_CHOICES + [('new_category', 'Add New')]
        self.fields['segment'].choices = Segment.SEGMENT_CHOICES + [('new_segment', 'Add New')]

        # Apply Bootstrap classes to the new category and segment fields
        self.fields['new_category'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['new_category'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter new category'
        self.fields['new_segment'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['new_segment'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Enter new segment'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        print("forms.py: ", cleaned_data)
        
        print(f"Before setting - category: {cleaned_data.get('category')}, segment: {cleaned_data.get('segment')}")

        # Set the values for new category and new segment
        cleaned_data['category'] = cleaned_data.get('new_category', cleaned_data.get('category'))
        cleaned_data['segment'] = cleaned_data.get('new_segment', cleaned_data.get('segment'))
        
        # Print values after setting them
        print(f"After setting - category: {cleaned_data.get('category')}, segment: {cleaned_data.get('segment')}")


        # Check if either an existing category or a new one is provided
        if not cleaned_data.get('category'):
            self.add_error('category', 'Please select an existing category or provide a new one.')

        if not cleaned_data.get('segment'):
            self.add_error('segment', 'Please select an existing segment or provide a new one.')

        return cleaned_data
```

**this is my models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('investments', 'Investments'),
        ('loans', 'Loans'),
        ('insurance', 'Insurance'),
        ('taxes', 'Taxes'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Segment(models.Model):
    SEGMENT_CHOICES = [
        ('investments', 'Investments'),
        ('expenses', 'Expenses'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=SEGMENT_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class LineItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    segment = models.ForeignKey(Segment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_of_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**this is my views.py**

```
@login_required
def lineitems(request):
    
    initial_data = {'category': 'default_category', 'segment': 'default_segment'}
    print("request.POST: ", request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LineItemForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        print("errors: ", form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            line_item = form.save(commit=False)
            line_item.user = request.user
            line_item.save()
            return redirect('Dashboard:lineitems')  # Redirect to a success page or another view
    else:
        form = LineItemForm(user=request.user, initial=initial_data)

    return render(request, 'Dashboard/lineitems.html', {'form': form})
```

The idea is as follows

1. There is a form with two dropdowns. Category and segment. There are default choices and the user can create new categories or segments if required.
2. Any category or segment the user creates is specific to that user and does not show for other users

I am printing the request.POST query set when the form is submitted and I get the following result

```
request.POST:  <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['zG8My4ID5S5uWn6vYesF3xxpEmfXA8DANbR9goRtpLDuqfKUMcrM4QKthdrwsth'], 'name': ['Mutual Funds'], 'category': ['investments'], 'new_category': [''], 'segment': ['investments'], 'new_segment': ['']}>
```

You can see that data from the form is being print out correctly. But in the clean method in forms.py the data is missing

```
forms.py:  {'name': 'Mutual Funds', 'new_category': '', 'new_segment': ''}
Before setting - category: None, segment: None
After setting - category: , segment:
```

It is interesting to note that only the dropdown values are missing. The line item name is being correctly printed.

I looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165944/select-widget-value-appearing-in-post-but-not-cleaned-data) but it did not seem to solve my issue.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: 1. what are the printed errors showing? 2. Can you try to pass the initial data for post as well? `form = LineItemForm(request.POST, user=request.user, initial=initial_data)`? The user kwarg can be popped inside init method to avoid `unexpected argument` error.